# D3js minimal reusable module not looping?

Tags: d3.js

I'am learning to create D3js reusable modules following Mike's [Towards Reusable Charts article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/), Christophe Viau's [The D3 Reusable API Speech](http://youtu.be/EoAY0hArT80) (mins 10 to 20) and [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvLX4/1/) I found on Stackoverflow. My simplified reusable module is expected to produces 4 x 2 rectangles, but currently just produce the 2 first then fails to loop properly upon the rest of my data :

```
//Data
var data = [
    {row: 0, col: 0, value: [{x: 1, y: 19}, {x: 2, y: 20}]}, // <= This only is produced!
    {row: 0, col: 1, value: [{x: 1, y: 24}, {x: 2, y: 27}]}, // <= from there it fails
    {row: 1, col: 1, value: [{x: 1, y: 31}, {x: 2, y: 26}]},
    {row: 1, col: 2, value: [{x: 1, y: 29}, {x: 2, y: 19}]}
];
```

JS which should loop over my data :

```
function exports(_selection) { // create function to export
    _selection.each(function(_data) { // loop
        var test_data = _data.value;
        var rectW = (_data.row+2)*10,
            rectH = (_data.col+1)*10;

        // Select all bars and bind data:
        var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
                    .data(test_data)
                .enter().append("rect");

        console.log(i+": "+JSON.stringify(_data.value));

    // design svg elements
    bars.attr("class","bar")
        .attr({
            'width': rectH,
            'x': function (d){ console.log(" log place1! "); return d.x * 10;},
            'y': function (d){ return d.y * 4;},
            'height': rectH*4});
        console.log(" log place2! ");

    });
}// exports end
```

**How to make it loop ?**  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvLX4/10/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you `call(chart)` the function ends up re-selecting the bars that you previously drew into the svg and not creating any new ones. Also, coincidentally, the pre-existing bars don't get repainted as part of the subsequent updates (under `// design svg elements`), because you assigned `bars` to the results of the `enter()` instead of to just the results of the `data()` binding.

You probably want to create a container per pair of bars. You can use d3 binding instead of the `for` loop that you wrote. Something like this:

```
// Module and custom settings
var chart = d3.coolmodules.barChart()
    .width(800).height(800);
// Runs
svg.selectAll("g").data(data)
  .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        return 'translate(' + (i*50) + ',0)';// Space the <g>'s horizontally
    })
    .call(chart);
```

And another important change is to replace

```
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
```

with

```
var bars = d3.select(this).selectAll(".bar")
```

The latter operates on each `g` assigned to a pair of bars. The former was operating on the entire svg. It seems inappropriate for the reusable component to have access to the `svg` you create. The main reason for passing a d3 selection into a module function is to specify the container. That way, the component just deals with laying out its children, while the "parent" code that uses the component takes the responsibility of positioning the parent container.

Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/uvLX4/12/).